# Как решить задачу про передвижение робота из начальной точки в конечную?

Tags: java, while, switch

читаю задачу и не понимаю с чего начать решение... Получается нужно реализовать алгоритм передвижения робота из начальной точки в конечную точку и при этом учесть, что координаты x и y могут быть отрицательными.

Описание: На игровом поле находится робот. Позиция робота на поле описывается двумя целочисленным координатами: X и Y. Ось X смотрит слева направо, ось Y — снизу вверх.

В начальный момент робот находится в некоторой позиции на поле. Также известно, куда робот смотрит: вверх, вниз, направо или налево.  задача — привести робота в заданную точку игрового поля.

Робот описывается классом Robot. Вы можете пользоваться следующими его методами (реализация вам неизвестна):

```
    public class Robot {

    public Direction getDirection() {
        // текущее направление взгляда
    }

    public int getX() {
        // текущая координата X
    }

    public int getY() {
        // текущая координата Y
    }

    public void turnLeft() {
        // повернуться на 90 градусов против часовой стрелки
    }

    public void turnRight() {
        // повернуться на 90 градусов по часовой стрелке
    }

    public void stepForward() {
        // шаг в направлении взгляда
        // за один шаг робот изменяет одну свою координату на единицу
    }
}
Direction, направление взгляда робота,  — это перечисление:
public enum Direction {
    UP,
    DOWN,
    LEFT,
    RIGHT
}
```

Как это  выглядит: см картинка

Пример:

В метод передано:

```
toX == 3, toY == 0; начальное состояние робота такое: robot.getX() == 0, robot.getY() == 0, robot.getDirection() == Direction.UP

Чтобы привести робота в указанную точку (3, 0), метод должен вызвать у робота следующие методы:

robot.turnRight();
robot.stepForward();
robot.stepForward();
robot.stepForward();
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSdX4.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Определяете "справа" или "слева" горизонтальная координата куда надо идти (вычитанием текущей координаты рорбота из цеелвой координаты). Кроме направления этот метод даст расстояние до цели (например если текущая координата -2, а целевая -7, то -7-(-2) = -5, что значит, что цель находится на 5 шагов левее по "иксу")
2. Определяете "сверху" или "снизу" вертикальная координата (таким же способом)
3. Определяете текущее направление робота. Ваша задача пройти нужное количество шагов по вертикали, потом повернуть и пройти нужное количество шагов по горизонтали (или наоборот)
4. Исходя из текущего направления робота решаете сколько раз надо повернуться. Например в шаге 1 если направление робота "направо", то перед тем как начать движение, необходимо повернуться налево и еще раз налево (развернув его на 180 градусов).
5. На каждом шаге решаете дошлел ли робот до нужной координаты и если да, снова переходете к шагу 3 для движение (при необходимости) по следующей оси.

Comment: Alexey R. спасибо большое за подробный ответ, попробую написать код.